# MODIS Landsat overlapping

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, landsat-7, modis-reprojection-tool

I have two Lands Surface Temperature images, one from Landsat 7 and the other one is from MODIS, both for the same day. After projecting MODIS to UTM WGS84 the two images are slightly shifted, i.e. they do not well overlap.

Is there any suggestion to fix the matter?

Comment: ArcGIS has a way to set a start point for a raster. Does the MODIS reprojection tool? Maybe adjust the corner coordinate value?

Comment: Which tools are you using? Can you show some example images?

Comment: I worked with QGIS first, then I tried with the HEG tool but still the image appears a bit moved. If I put images here it will not be appreciable actually. I see it when I have the images overlapping.

Comment: I will try with the ArcGIS to set the start point as you suggest.